# How to swap users in Linux through GitHub workflow?

Tags: linux, github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm having Github workflow to run a python file. Before running the python file I want to swap user so that no sudo is required to execute the python file.

I tried with **'su'** but it's says **su must be run from command line**. How to do that through Github Workflow. Thank you

> .yaml

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
     branches: [ main ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python: [3.8.1]
        
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
    - name: run multiple commands
      run: |
        echo $PWD
        whoami 
        su - user
        python helloworld.py
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/44408/277950 also, are you sure you want your self-hosted runner to be running as root?

Comment: @rethab when I'm using the default user I'm getting **permissionError: [Errno 13] Permission** error. So I want to change to another user so that it may run python file.

Comment: which one is your default user? You should run the runner with a user that has write access to the workspace.

Comment: @rethab **mainuser** is the name of default user

Comment: assuming that `mainuser` is not root, can you give that user w+ permissions to the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a secret that is having the ssh key of the user you want to switch to. Using that script you can ssh to localhost with the intended user to execute commands as the intended user.

```
ssh -i <key-path> <user>@<remote-machine> -t '<command>'
```